# automapper class to struct

Tags: c#, automapper

Is it actually possible to map a class to a struct using [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/)?

At the moment I am getting:

```
{"The type initializer for 'AutoMapper.TypeMapFactory' threw an exception."}
```

This is my simplified code:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<A, B>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.a, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.b))
.ForMember(dest => dest.c, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.d))
.ForMember(dest => dest.f, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.g));
```

Here A is a class and B is a struct.

Comment: And what exception did it throw? It should be contained as an InnerException.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is completely possible to map class instance to struct - AutoMapper do not have any constraints on generic type parameters, and it works fine with structs. E.g. if you have

```
public class A
{
    public string b { get; set; }
    public int d { get; set; }
    public bool g { get; set; }
}

public struct B
{
    public bool f;
    public string a;
    public int c;
}
```

With your mapping following code works just fine:

```
var a = new A { b = "b", d = 42, g = false };
var b = Mapper.Map<B>(a);
```

Comment: Sorry - I do not think this can work. How does automapper know how to map b of A to f of B?

Comment: @csetzkorn as I told, from your mapping

Comment: Ok thanks. It turned out that I got a per-release version from nuget.

Comment: @csetzkorn yep pre-release versions are interesting, but they often have surprises. Btw consider to use PascalCase naming for properties and public fields